# R webcorpus attribute extraction

Tags: r, attributes, text-mining, tm, corpus

I am using the **tm.plugin.webmining** to get latest news about a company say microsoft using the following command

```
corpus<-WebCorpus(GoogleBlogSearchSource(stock))
```

When I run **meta(corpus[[1]])** i get

> Metadata:
>
> > author       : character(0)
> >     datetimestamp: 2014-07-17 20:28:10
> >     description  : Microsoft Layoffs ÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â€ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â“ What it Means for MSFT StockInvestorplace.comWhile the layoffs are obviously
> >     going to be hardest on the workers, as investors we still have to take
> >     a rational and objective look at the corporation to see what it means
> >     for MSFT ÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â€ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â“ particularly if you are personally a
> >     Microsoft stock holder ...Why Microsoft (MSFT) Stock Is Up
> >     TodayTheStreet.comEarnings Preview: Microsoft Corporation (MSFT),
> >     Apple Inc (AAPL), Facebook ...International Business TimesWhat Do
> >     Microsoft's Layoff Plans Tell Us About Satya Nadella's Vision?Motley
> >     FoolTech InsiderÂ -Insider Monkey (blog)all 2,176 news articlesÂ Â»
> >     heading      : Microsoft Layoffs ÃƒÂ¢Ã‚Â€Ã‚Â“ What it Means for MSFT Stock - Investorplace.com
> >     id           : tag:news.google.com,2005:cluster=http://investorplace.com/2014/07/microsoft-layoffs-means-msft-stock/
> >     language     : character(0)
> >     origin       : http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNEadqFvThyxvJU3O5uHa6wiyoWNEw&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&cid=52778559643673&ei=Cr3LU8jGNMnNkwX_lYCICQ&url=http://investorplace.com/2014/07/microsoft-layoffs-means-msft-stock/

So here I see that the different attributes are here but when I run

```
Headers<-sapply(meta(corpus,FUN=function(x){attr(x,"heading")})
```

Headers is a list of 100 items with null values. I am pretty sure this particular code was running a few days back. What changed in between was I reinstalled the packages on the new system and also updated R to 3.1.1 instead of R 3.1.0(earlier)

What can I do to get separate lists of headers, descriptions timestamp, etc, which I later want to convert into a 100X3 data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the newest R, Please try the following code:

Code :

```
headers<-meta(corpus,tag="heading")
```